# "Part of its charm" en francais

Tags: phrase

Est-ce que la phrase suivante est correcte:

> Dans ma maison c'est toujours le bordel mais à mes yeux c'est aussi ce qui fait son charme

En anglais ce que j'esssaie de dire correspond à peu près à ce qui suit:

> In my house it's always a mess but in my eyes that's also part of its charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dans ma maison c'est toujours le bordel mais à mes yeux c'est aussi ce qui fait son charme

Cette phrase est grammaticalement correcte et a à peu près le sens voulu. En revanche, son niveau de langue est incohérent : « bordel » est très familier, et l'absence complète de ponctuation n'est possible que dans une langue écrite relâchée. L'utilisation d'une tournure impersonnelle « c'est » est fréquente en langue familière, mais en général évitée en langue soutenue si on peut faire autrement. En revanche, la construction relativement complexe de la phrase et la formulation « à mes yeux » appartiennent plutôt à une langue soutenue.

Voici une formulation soutenue idiomatique, avec quelques variations qui ont le même sens.

> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, cela fait aussi partie de son charme.
> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, cela en fait aussi partie du charme.
> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, c'est aussi ce qui fait son charme.
> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, c'est aussi ce qui en fait le charme.

Plutôt qu'« en désordre », on peut peut-être préférer « dans un certain désordre » ou « dans un désordre certain ». La deuxième formulation est plus forte que la première (« X certain » > « certain X »).

Voici quelques formulations familières idiomatiques, avec des sens quasiment identique sauf une très légère variation dans l'expression du caractère subjectif du jugement sur le charme.

> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais ça fait aussi partie du charme.
> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais ça fait aussi partie de son charme.   (Plus précis, mais un peu lourd. En général on dirait plutôt « du charme » et c'est à l'interlocuteur de deviner de quel charme on parle.)
> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais je trouve que ça fait partie du charme.
> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais pour moi ça fait partie du charme.

Et voici quelques variations (soutenues avec « désordre », familières avec « bordel ») qui correspondent à « *it's part of its charm* », sans référence à une autre chose qui lui donne du charme.

> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, cela fait partie de son charme.
> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, cela en fait partie du charme.
> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais ça fait partie du charme.
> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais ça fait aussi partie du charme.   (En langue familière, on peut utiliser « faire aussi partie » sans que *aussi* fasse référence à quelque chose dont on a déjà parlé. C'est une façon courante de renforcer « faire partie », sans vraiment changer le sens.)

Et voici aussi quelques variations qui correspondent à « *it's what gives it its charm* », sans implications que le charme ait d'autres sources.

> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, c'est ce qui lui donne son charme.
> Ma maison est toujours en désordre, mais, à mes yeux, c'est ce qui lui confère un certain charme.
> Dans ma maison, c'est toujours le bordel. Mais je trouve que ça fait son charme.

Comment: You have really covered all the possible bases, but bear in mind that in English, "In my house, it's always a mess" *verges on the unidiomatic*. One is more likely to find: At my house, there is etc. OR My house is always a mess but the way I see it, that's part of its charm. In any event, the tone is colloquial and informal...And in my view, in colloquial language everyone says bordel in French for a mess.

Answer (score 3):

*Chez moi, c'est tout le temps le bazar, mais je trouve que **ça fait partie du charme des lieux**.*

Voici un exemple d'utilisation de cette expression :

> Barbara Raine, sa propriétaire, assure qu’il ne faut pas se fier aux apparences : « Une clochette retentit dans une chambre, une porte se déverrouille seule, des meubles bougent sur le balcon… Mais ça fait partie du charme des lieux ! » [Emmanuel Romer](https://polar.blogs.la-croix.com/au-canada-three-pines-accueillant-village-fictif/2019/10/10/)

<sub>Notes sur les choix du reste du vocabulaire : Comme l'a justement signalé Gilles, *bordel* est de registre très familier et détonne avec le reste de la phrase, *bazar* n'a pas ce défaut. *[Chez](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chez) moi* est beaucoup plus courant que *dans ma maison* et à sensiblement la même signification. *Toujours* est parfois ambigu en signifiant *encore*, *tout le temps* le remplace mais ce n'était pas indispensable. *À mes yeux c'est* est peut-être un peu trop soutenu et remplacé par *je trouve que*, plus courant.</sub>

Comment: les lieux veut dire: the premises.

Comment: @Lambie *Les lieux* veut dire *les lieux*. Essaie d'oublier l'anglais.

Comment: Pour ta citation, on trouve dans le texte au paragraphe précédent: de Old House Mansion, **une immense demeure rose finalement séduisante**. Lá, ce n'est pas pareil à la "petite" phrase de la question. Dans l'article canadien, la cooccurrence fonctionne parfaitement !  Et puis, **l'auteur ne parle pas de "chez moi"**, comme ayant un charme des lieux, n'est-ce pas?.

Comment: @Lambie Si j'ai bien compris on ne peut parler du _charme des lieux_ quand le lieu n'est pas assez grand et quand il y a _chez moi_ dans la phrase.

Comment: @Lambie ***Les lieux*** n'implique pas que l'on désigne quoi que ce soit d'étendu. Ce pluriel est trompeur car il n'indique pas qu'il s'agit d'un ensemble de plusieurs endroits, *les lieux* peut même parfois désigner la pièce la plus petite de la maison...

Comment: Larousse: Lieux, 
nom masculin pluriel 1. **Locaux, terrain** : Les nouveaux locataires ont visité les lieux.
2. Familier. Les W.-C.

Comment: @Lambie Exactement, Les W.-C. ne sont généralement pas une immense demeure rose séduisante et s'il n'y en a qu'un, le mot reste au pluriel. [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lieux) *II. − Au pluriel A. − Vieilli et littér. [**Le pluriel exprime la singularité**] [....] 2. Usuel et dans le vocab. jur. [...] b) **Maison**, immeuble.*

Answer (score 0):

> Johnson, plus complexe qu'il n'y paraît [TITRE]
>
> Cette trompeuse victoire de la clarté a été incarnée par un homme,
> parfaitement britannique dans son excentricité, mais contenant - *cela
> fait partie de son charme* - une part de mystère.

Edito[rial]

[Journal LesEchos](https://www.lesechos.fr/idees-debats/editos-analyses/boris-johnson-ou-la-democratie-triomphante-1156668)

Why not say: My house is always a mess?

« Chez moi, c'est toujours le bordel mais à mes yeux ça fait partie de son charme. »

Comment: I don't know why people even bother to downvote. I guess the French language as quoted from LesEchos is no good. I merely copied it.